# Android Lollipop defaults to Mobile Data when Wi-Fi has not Internet access?

Tags: android, connection, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

`Android Lollipop` seems to default to Mobile Data when the `Wi-Fi` you are connected to has no Internet access. Does anybody know if this is officially documented somewhere?

We have an application that needs to connect to machines via `Wi-Fi` that do not have Internet. Our customers are now reporting that the `Wi-Fi` connection does not work anymore, because the phone automatically switches to `LTE`.

My understanding would be that the phone still keeps the `Wi-Fi` connection but uses `LTE` in addition to provide access to the Internet ([lollipop-feature-spotlight-android-now-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-no-internet-access-signal-icon-adds-a-for-no-connection](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/18/lollipop-feature-spotlight-android-now-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-no-internet-access-signal-icon-adds-a-for-no-connection/)).

Is my understanding of this feature wrong? And if so, is there a way to force using the Wi-Fi without Internet? I could not find anything about this in particular in the developer documentation.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To extend on @ianhanniballake's answer, I've found that binding the network using [ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) prevents roaming and allows for full TCP access. Thus, within the [onAvailable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html#onAvailable(android.net.Network)) callback you could bind the application process to that network rather than opening a connection to a particular URL.

```
ConnectivityManager connection_manager = 
    (ConnectivityManager) activity.getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);

connection_manager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new NetworkCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
    }
}
```

As of API Level 23: Please use the following OnAvailable Method:

```
@Override
public void onAvailable(Network network) {
    connection_manager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, what if while downloading from server wifi connection gone and mobile data got connected,as we are binding our process to wifi so it will wait for wifi connection?

Comment: For this to work on Android 9, you need to add the following permission to your app manifest: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

Answer (score 8):

By default, Android 5.0 will only send network requests over networks that it detect have an active internet connection so while it may be 'connected' to the wifi, it is not going to send any data over the network.

However, the [Android 5.0 APIs guide](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless) talks about the new multiple network support:

> Android 5.0 provides new multi-networking APIs that let your app dynamically scan for available networks with specific capabilities, and establish a connection to them. This functionality is useful when your app requires a specialized network, such as an SUPL, MMS, or carrier-billing network, or if you want to send data using a particular type of transport protocol.

This allows you to build a [NetworkRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.html) for a [TRANSPORT_WIFI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#TRANSPORT_WIFI) type and direct traffic to it via [Network.openConnection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)) when you receive a [onAvailable() callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html#onAvailable(android.net.Network)) if you must have certain connections happen over wifi even when the wifi network does not have internet access.

Comment: That seems stupid, why not route traffic to the interfaces based on the destination subnet?

Comment: @MaxEhrlich - if you have a better implementation please do [submit a patch](https://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html).

Comment: I shouldn't have to, every other OS does this already. Google clearly has it in their mind how they want it to work and would probably reject such a patch

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, I am on the browser trying to connect to my local server over wifi which is not connected to internet... Since lollipop I can't access the local server as it is trying to connect via mobile network. What Max suggested shoudl be the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Android 5.0 provides new multi-networking APIs that let your app dynamically scan for available networks with specific capabilities, and establish a connection to them.
[More info here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless)

So solution for you is [ConnectivityManager.requestNetwor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestNetwork%28android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for those who try to solve the connectivity problem from within their own app. But for those who come here looking for a solution to access a non-internet-WiFi with some standard app like Google Chrome:

You simply have to disabled "Mobile Data" in your phone settings and Chrome or any other App will readily access your WiFi.