# mono_w32socket_convert_error: no translation into winsock error for (64) "Machine is not on the network"

Tags: android, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to control my APP's network go through Mobile/WiFi

So I follow this post [40216514](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578475/how-to-connect-to-local-network-first-instead-of-internet-in-c-sharp-xamarin-and)

But when I tried to turn on WiFi. And make wifi be my major network.

Then I tried to do some communication. Very high possiblity(90%) the APP crash.

How can I avoid it?

Thank you!

Here is my code.

```
public void SomeFunction() 
{ 
    await ForceWifiOverCellular();

    try
    {
        app_connection_request app_connection_request = new app_connection_request
        {
            url = "app_con_req",
            request = mode,
        };

        Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "91/n";
        // Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
        var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(app_connection_request));

        // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
        var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var myHttpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
        };

        Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "92/n"; //Crash at here
        var resp = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, httpContent);


        Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "93/n";
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "94/n";
            var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "95/n";
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RS485_Info>(resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return -1; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Settings.Log_Item_Scan += "96/n";
        return -1;
    }
}
public async static Task<int> ForceWifiOverCellular()
{
    await WiFi_Control_Center.Set_WiFI_Enable(true); //This code is to turn on wifi

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    ConnectivityManager connection_manager = (ConnectivityManager)_context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

    NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    request.AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi);

    var callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback();
    connection_manager.RegisterNetworkCallback(request.Build(), new CustomNetworkAvailableCallBack());

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    return 0;
}

public static async Task Set_WiFI_Enable(bool enabled)
{
    try
    {

    WifiManager Temp_WiFi = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    Temp_WiFi.SetWifiEnabled(enabled);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    catch
    { 
    }
}
```

Here is some log

> 06-12 20:47:25.355 D/Mono    (14255): Assembly
>   System.Reflection.Primitives[0xad468660] added to domain RootDomain,
>   ref_count=1 06-12 20:47:25.356 D/Mono    (14255): AOT: image
>   'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app/com.mydeltasolar_1_0_1.app-uRHsm2P_-FnLPQC6AXJTDA==/lib/arm/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so"
>   not found 06-12 20:47:25.356 D/Mono    (14255): AOT: image
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app/com.mydeltasolar_1_0_1.app-uRHsm2P_-FnLPQC6AXJTDA==/lib/arm/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so"
>   not found 06-12 20:47:25.356 D/Mono    (14255): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.config'. 06-12 20:47:25.356
>   D/Mono    (14255): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection.Primitives/System.Reflection.Primitives.config'.
>   06-12 20:47:25.356 D/Mono    (14255): Assembly Ref addref
>   Newtonsoft.Json[0xed1995c0] ->
>   System.Reflection.Primitives[0xad468660]: 2 06-12 20:47:25.357 D/Mono 
>   (14255): Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection.Primitives[0xad468660]
>   -> mscorlib[0xed1991a0]: 91 Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External] Xamarin.Android returned
>   no custom HttpClientHandler. Defaulting to
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler 06-12 20:47:25.502
>   I/mono-stdout(14255): Xamarin.Android returned no custom
>   HttpClientHandler. Defaulting to System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
>   06-12 20:47:25.519 F/        (14255): mono_w32socket_convert_error: no
>   translation into winsock error for (64) "Machine is not on the
>   network" 06-12 20:47:25.534 D/ConnectivityManager(14255):
>   setProcessDefaultNetwork CallingUid : 10532, CallingPid : 14255 06-12
>   20:47:25.534 D/ConnectivityManager_URSP(14255): hong blacklisted -
>   false 06-12 20:47:26.090 F/libc    (14255): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT),
>   code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 14362 (Thread Pool Wor), pid 14255
>   (solar_1_0_1.app) 06-12 20:47:27.252 D/InputMethodManager(14255):
>   HSIFW - flag : 0 Pid : 14255

Comment: If you comment out your ForceWifiOverCellular function, are you still seeing the crash? Also could you share your Android build project options, specifically the part about the HTTPClientHandler being used? Also does the URL begin with https or http?