# How to check if both Mobile Data and WIFI are connected?

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have this code:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo networkInfoWifi =
  connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

NetworkInfo networkInfoMobileData =
  connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

And then in my Android network settings, both Mobile Data and WiFi are enabled. The following checks are

```
networkInfoWifi.isConnected();       // results to TRUE
networkInfoMobileData.isConnected(); // results to FALSE
```

My app runs on Android Lollipop. I expect that both checks above should return TRUE. Why is this happening? I need them to be both TRUE. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to make the `networkInfoWifi.isConnected()` and
`networkInfoMobileData.isConnected()` to return both TRUE. This is probably because Android can only be connected to only one interface at a time.

This interface selection is also done by Android automatically starting Lollipop devices. [Android Lollipop defaults to Mobile Data when Wi-Fi has not Internet access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164298/android-lollipop-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-not-internet-access/27164746#27164746)

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo()` is a deprecated method.

The right thing to do is to make a `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`

#### To answer your question, checking whether you are connected to the internet via WiFi or Mobile Data:

```
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .build();

    connMgr.requestNetwork(request, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        // This callback is invoked when there is a valid Mobile Data or WiFi network 
        // but is later lost during the course of using the application.
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
        }


        // This callback is invoked when there is a valid Mobile Data or WiFi network 
        // that is ready for use
        @Override
        public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onLost(network);
        }


        // This callback is invoked when there is no valid Mobile Data or WiFi network 
        // after a specific timeout has timed out.
        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable();
        }
    });
```

There are various other callbacks, but I believe for your use case these are the primary ones you would need.
Finally, the to add a specific timeout, that was mentioned in the `onUnavailable` callback, you can use this Constructor for your `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`:

`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(int timeoutMs)`

I really do hope this helps. See more information on the API [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for your answer. By the way, I am targeting a Lollipop device. `ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo()` is still valid on this platform. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)

Comment: @user1506104 okay then.